# What phrase or verb do use to say that you are at university but study from home?

Tags: phrase-choice

What phrase or verb do use to say that you are at university but study from home? Is it natural say *study remotely* or *study distantly*? For example:

> I was at university, but I **studied** **remotely**/**distantly**.

Comment: What's wrong with your own expression i.e. 'from home'?

Comment: I don't know. I am not a native English speaker that is why I asked the question.

Comment: Is studying from home your own choice or is there no other possibllity (distance study)?

Comment: You could say "I was enrolled at university, but I studied at home."